# Swift 3 - Queue of one item only

Tags: ios, swift, queue

I'm processing frames from a live video feed with OpenCV, and the processing is quite intensive. It can take between 2-3 seconds. It is ok to ignore all the frames which are recorded while a frame is being processed.

Basically, we have a continuous flow of frames being displayed in the foreground. We take the next available frame and process it in the background. For the next 2-3 seconds as this frame processes, I want all of the next frames to continue displaying in the foreground uninterrupted. I do not need to process these. However, as soon as the background frame is finished, I want to grab the newest frame available and send that off for processing.

I am new to queues in Swift. I assume it is queues I should be looking at, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to use the background DispatchQueue. Do the frame processing asynchronously, then switch back to the main queue to show the results and call the function recursively, until you decide to stop. It's especially important to switch back to the main thread to make any UI updates.

```
func processNextAvailableFrame() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // Grab a frame to process
        // Process frame

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Back on main thread, show result of processing frame
            // Call processFrame() again, as needed.
            let shouldKeepGoing = true // determine this somehow
            if shouldKeepGoing {
                self.processNextAvailableFrame()
            }
        }
    }
}
```